# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+ Error (24, 13)

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

When I am trying to build a new project in android studio, I get this message and "Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+ Error (24, 13)" with a link like the following "Install Repository and sync project".But the real problem is when I click on the link i get a message "All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id extras;android;m2repository". Please help me...These are the screen shots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnFPX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhTv2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Issue:
I was getting the same error. The problem was older code that was using an older version of `com.android.support:appcompat` namely 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' in the `build.gradle` (Module:app) and I was compiling with `compileSdkVersion 25`.

Solution:
Update the dependency section to 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' in the module level build.gradle file. If this solves your issue please vote for my answer.